# Existe algum motivo para uma medalha de tag não ser dada?

Tags: suporte, medalhas

No dia 30 de março atingi 20 respostas na *tag* [exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e já tinha mais de 100 votos obtidos nela como [mostra a busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]). Nenhuma é wiki.

A [página de medalhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) mostra que os números para a medalha de bronze são estes. Existe algum critério adicional?

Ou é apenas um *bug*?

Comment: Foi apenas uma exceção.

Comment: Mais precisamente, uma `NullBadgeException`. Acho que faltou um `catch`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tag ainda não tem perguntas suficientes para fazer parte do sistema de medalhas. [Segundo o MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/167534), só são oferecidas medalhas em tags com pelo menos 100 perguntas, e [exceção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%c3%a7%c3%a3o) no momento só tem 64.

Comment: Eu tinha quase certeza que era isto.